# loopback: how to load model instances based on a relation's property

Tags: javascript, tags, has-many-through, loopback

I have a model `Book`.

`Book` can have multiple tags, so there is a hasMany relationship to `Tag` through `BookTags`

Now, how do I load all `Book` instances with tag "history" (for example)?
It should be trivial, but I couldn't find out.

In the documentation, there are only examples for values of properties (like strings, booleans etc.) but no examples for loading via relationships. There is the `include`filter which loads relationships, but that should apply to loading relationship instances, which is something else (AFAI understand);

I tried:

```
Book.find({
    where: {tags: {name: "history"}}
}, function(err, books) {
}
```

But that does not work at all.
My next bet was trying to load the Tag by id and try to filter by object, but I would not even know how to do it, as there are no "contains" operators in the where clause documentation:
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter#Wherefilter-inq

The ultimate workaround is to:

- load the tag via name
- load all `BookTags` instances with that tag id, get the book ids
- load all Books with those ids

Seems cumbersome and suggests there should be a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

If a book can have many tags, and a tag can have many books, it sounds like you need the hasAndBelongsToMany relationship. This relationship is great for many-to-many's that don't have any additional payload.

**common/models/book.json**

```
{
  "name": "Book",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "Title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "Author": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "tags": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "Tag",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**common/models/tag.json**

```
{
  "name": "Tag",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "books": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "Book",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

How to access it? Here is an example boot script that creates some tags and books, and accesses them.

**server/boot/seed.js**

```
var async = require('async');
module.exports = function(app) {

    var Tag = app.models.Tag;
    var Book = app.models.Book;

    var tags = [{Name: "Scifi"}, {Name: "Adventure"}];

    Book.create({Title: "Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea", author: "Jules Verne"}, function(err, book){
        console.log('Book: ' + book);

        async.each(tags, function(tag, done){
            book.tags.create(tag, done);
        }, function(err){
            //Book > Tag
            console.log("Book " + book.Title + " has these tags: ");
            console.log(book.tags())
            //Tag > Book

            Tag.findOne({where: {Name: "Scifi"}, include: 'books'},function(err, foundTag){
                console.log("    - Tag " + foundTag.Name + " has these books:");
                console.log(foundTag.books());

            });
        });
    });
};
```

Output:

```
Book Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea has these tags: 
[ { Name: 'Scifi', id: 1 }, { Name: 'Adventure', id: 2 } ]

Tag Scifi has these books:
[ { 
    Title: 'Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea',
    author: 'Jules Verne',
    id: 1 
} ]
```